# How can I construct a lyrics scrolling view with highlight on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'd like to make a view like the following.

[image]

What would be views hierarchy in this case?

I was planning to use UITextView with highlighted UIView. But it doesn't work really well when the lyric is more than one line.

What would be the easiest and painless way to implement it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use UITableView.

Comment: @SidShah wow, lol that's clever. not sure if that'd be the right way to do it. but yeah, i'll give it a shot.